# rework preg_replace with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, serialization, preg-replace-callback

I've seen many answers about this but as this one is a bit specific, I still need some help.  I'm trying to update Blogstudio's [Fix Serialization](https://github.com/Blogestudio/Fix-Serialization/blob/master/fix-serialization.php) script which contains `preg_replace()` with `\e` modifier.

The code in question is this:

```
$data = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):([\\\\]?"[\\\\]?"|[\\\\]?"((.*?)[^\\\\])[\\\\]?");!e', "'s:'.strlen(unescape_mysql('$3')).':\"'.unescape_quotes('$3').'\";'", $data);
```

The confusion for me lies in:

1. Whether those functions are intending to address escaped quotes due to the `/e` modifier or not?
2. What the result should be when there is not a `$3`?

I had rewritten it as this but still running into warnings and other problems so the result is not the same as what's intended:

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    '!s:(\d+):([\\\\]?"[\\\\]?"|[\\\\]?"((.*?)[^\\\\])[\\\\]?");!',
    function($d) {
        $length = strlen(unescape_mysql($d[3]));
        $value = unescape_quotes($d[3]);
        $result = 's:' . $length . ':\"' . $value . '\";';
        return 's:' . $length . ':\"' . $value . '\";'
    },
    $data
);
```

Comment: What warnings and other problems?

Comment: `undefined offset 3` is the only warning.  not 100% sure about the escaped characters but I can port this all over to another server with an older version of php to compare.  by "problems" i'm referring to the fact that my output is wrong since the replacement function is referring to an offset which doesn't exist in some cases.  apparently that's just fine with `preg_replace()` but not in this case.

Comment: The first thing to do is to remove all these useless capture groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem:

```
s:(\d+): # group 1
(        # group 2
    [\\\\]?"[\\\\]?"
  |
    [\\\\]?"
    ((.*?)[^\\\\]) # group 3 (and 4)
    [\\\\]?"
)
;
```

As you can see there's an alternation with 2 branches inside the group 2. Groups 3 (and 4) are in the second branch, when the first branch succeeds these groups are not defined.

Let's clean the pattern removing useless capture groups:

```
s:\d+:
(?:
    [\\\\]? " [\\\\]? "
  |
    [\\\\]? "
    (.*? [^\\\\])      # group 1
    [\\\\]? "
)
;
```

Now the target group is the group 1, but the branch problem remains. There's two possible ways to solve it:

- you can test if the index exists with `isset` in the callback function.
- you can change the pattern in a way group 1 is defined in the two branches using the branch reset feature.

First way:

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
   '~s:\K\d+:(?:[\\\\]?"[\\\\]?"|[\\\\]?"(.*?[^\\\\])[\\\\]?");~', 
   function ($m) {
     return (isset($m[1]))
       ? strlen(unescape_mysql($m[1])) . ':\"' . $m[1] . '\";'
       : '0:\"\";';
   },
   $data
);
```

Second way (with the branch reset feature):

```
$data = preg_replace_callback(
   '~s:\K\d+:(?|[\\\\]?"[\\\\]?"()|[\\\\]?"(.*?[^\\\\])[\\\\]?");~', 
   function ($m) {
     return strlen(unescape_mysql($m[1])) . ':\"' . $m[1] . '\";';
   },
   $data
);
```

In a branch reset group capture groups have the same numbers in each branch, to solve your problem you only need to create an empty capture group in the first branch:

```
(?|  # open a branch reset group
     foo
     ()  # capture group 1
  |
     bar
     (baz) # capture group 1 (too)
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Casimir - I've been so busy last couple days that I haven't had time to test this against the original to compare results.  Just wanted you to know that your insight is appreciated and I'll follow up soon.

Comment: Finally has a chance to review this today.  It mostly works but there were a couple small problems with your code so I edited the answer with corrections: (a) missing close parenthesis for `strlen()` and (b) the `unescape_quotes()` function is no longer necessary as it turns out it was meant to deal with the auto escaping of double quotes added by `preg_replace()` with the *`e`* modifier.  Thanks for your help